# Get Location updates in background mode & Terminated mode IOS

Tags: ios, swift4, core-location

I want to get location updates of user even after the app is terminated from background mode or if its in the background mode. It has to work for both the cases.please provide any demo link for the same.

Comment: I don't think it is possible for the app to gather location data while terminated. Also, you can't expect us to make a whole prototype to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the location update in terminated mode.

Please see : - [Getting User Current Location](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html)

For getting location in background please use the following code to authorization

```
locationManager = CLLocationManager()
locationManager?.delegate = self
locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
```

Authorization alert will be appear like this.

[image]

Select Always allow for getting location in background mode.